# Querying default account team member on user. How can I query the default account team member?

Tags: account-teams

I have some users that have a default account team on them with one team member who is another user. How can I query this user? I thought these users were UserTeamMembers but just doing

`Select Id FROM UserTeamMembers` returns no results even though I have several instances of default account team members on users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the default *Account* team members, query the [UserAccountTeamMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_useraccountteammember.htm).

```
SELECT TeamMemberRole, UserId, OwnerId FROM UserAccountTeamMember
```

The UserTeamMember table is for the default *Opportunity* team members.

Comment: D'oh, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @Josh Totally easy mistake to make. The name of the object is because of historical reasons; it would have been nice for it to be UserOpportunityTeamMember instead.